# C++ split string class in function not using strtok()

Tags: c++, string, split, token, tokenize

I have a default constructor function that takes in a string class variable (not `char*`) and needs to tokenize that string by a delimiter which in my particular case is a comma.  Since I am using the string class I cannot within my knowledge use `strtok()` because it expects a `char*` as an input and not a string class.  Given the code below how can I split the string into smaller strings given that the first two tokens are a string, the third an in and the fourth a `double`?

```
private string a;
private string b;
private int x;
private double y;

StrSplit::StrSplit(string s){
  a = // tokenize the first delimiter and assign it to a
  b = // tokenize the second delimiter and assign it to b
  x = // tokenize the third delimiter and assign it to x
  y = // tokenize the fourth delimiter and assign it to y
}
```

Comment: can you do s.cstr() into strtok(delimiter,s.cstr())? Can reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

Comment: using both #include string and #include cstring s.cstr() results in "std::string’ has no member named ‘cstr’"

Comment: It should be c_str()

Comment: Maverick that was it.  The only issue I am having now is that i have: "warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]."  I would like to take care of that error but have no clue how to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try bellow *source-code : ([test it online](http://cpp.sh/6zzog))*

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

std::string a;
std::string b;
int x;
double y;

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& s, char delimiter)
{
   std::vector<std::string> tokens;
   std::string token;
   std::istringstream tokenStream(s);
   while (std::getline(tokenStream, token, delimiter))
   {
      tokens.push_back(token);
   }
   return tokens;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "hello,how are you?,3,4";
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    vec = split(str, ',');

    a = vec[0];
    b = vec[1];
    x = std::stoi(vec[2]);              // support in c++11
    x = atoi(vec[2].c_str());
    y = std::stod(vec[2].c_str());      // support in c++11
    y = atof(vec[2].c_str());

    std::cout << a << "," << b << "," << x << "," << y << std::endl;

}
```

The output will be :

```
hello,how are you?,3,3
```

Comment: This ended up being the best method that worked.  I had to modify to code a little bit to get it working for my application but the getline(tokenStream, token, delimiter) is what worked.